# What's the best way to programmatically highlight strings in Jinja?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am working on some code to do quote identification/attribution in articles and I'd like to highlight the identified quotes in the HTML file the code generates.

I have a function which formats a Jinja/HTML file with the article text and metadata:

```
def render_doc(doc_id):
    # load article html into BeautifulSoup
    data = dl.load_file(doc_id) 
    soup = extract_soup(data)

    # extract metadata
    context = get_metadata(soup)
    context['bodytext'] = soup.bodytext

    # render and open html file
    path = './'
    filename = 'ln_template.html'

    rendered = Environment(
        loader=FileSystemLoader(path)
    ).get_template(filename).render(context)

    file_name = f"{doc_id}.html"

    with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
        f.write(rendered)

    os.system(f"open {file_name}")
```

If I have the text of the quotes, what would be the best way to add a `<mark>` tag or some css or otherwise highlight the text in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

ok just ended up swapping the quote for a span tag containing the quote after rendering the Jinja.

works for a list of quotes and takes the color as a variable as well.

```
def render_id(doc_id, dl=None, quotes=None, color='LightGreen'):
    if not dl:
        dl = docLoader()
    data = dl.load_file(doc_id)
    soup = extract_soup(data)
    context = get_metadata(soup)
    context['bodytext'] = soup.bodytext

    path = './'
    filename = 'ln_template.html'

    rendered = Environment(
        loader=FileSystemLoader(path)
    ).get_template(filename).render(context)

    if quotes:
        for q in quotes:
            rendered = rendered.replace(
                q, f"<span style=\"background-color: {color};\">{q}</span>"
            )

    file_name = f"{doc_id}.html"

    with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
        f.write(rendered)

    os.system(f"open {file_name}")
```